# Existing MVC web application on sitecore 9.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

Team,

I am a beginner on site core 9.0. We have a requirement to migrate the existing MVC 5.0 application to sitecore 9.0. I am trying to build a POC first by having a basic mvc 5.0 web application having a login page.

May i know step by step process to migrate this to site core 9.0. I have tried all resources...(may be i have missed some) and i am confused.

Can anyone please guide me with proper links/information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to start is by taking a brief introductory course into Sitecore to learn the terminology and how things are put together. There are also a lot of online resources to help you get started (Google "getting started with Sitecore").

Joining the community (like this one, the one on sitecore.stackexchange.com, Sitecore Slack, Community Forums) will put you in touch with a lot of developers who can help you through your steps as you move piece by piece.

Your particular question here is a little too vague to answer accurately. There are a lot of things that need to be done and it all depends on your scenario and your existing MVC application. It may be more helpful to ask specifics about a particular scenario you are migrating, with code examples, and what you have tried already.

You also need to think about what you are trying to migrate. Are you moving to run off of a Content Delivery server? Or are you building your MVC application to consume Sitecore as a headless application? Those would be two entirely different migration approaches.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for your reply. Well..my objective is to create a homepage with different menus on it and also a login functionality with a login box and password. it will also have a sign up link below. Can you help me with this requirement.  I am not sure what a headless sitecore application means. I can very well design a mvc 5.0 application with all this but my doubt is that how will I integrate this with Sitecore 9.0. if you go to the sitecore webroot url it will present you the site core login and password screen box. Will my homepage appear after I login successfully as admin ?

Comment: I would recommend you reworking your question to the specific challenges, like you did in the question above, and work one step at a time. Getting a basic homepage to display is probably a good step. I strongly recommend the free eLearning course from Sitecore to learn the basics.

As for headless, this is when you run an application not on Sitecore but call the Sitecore APIs to get content or layout, depending on how you build.